# Singleton class variable in swift?

Tags: swift, variables, singleton

I am trying to create a Singleton class, where I want to create an instance of UIImage.

In Objective-C

we can simple declare a property in .h like

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)UIImage *pic;
```

and define a sharedSingleton Method in .m

```
+(SingletonClass*)sharedSingleton{
  @synchronized(self){

   if (!sharedSingleton) {
       sharedSingleton=[[SingletonClass alloc]init];

   }
   return sharedSingleton;
}
}
```

and call from any class with

```
 [SingletonClass sharedSingleton].pic
```

I am searching from last 2 hours but didn't find ant suitable tutorial to create this.  please help me out to create a singleton class in swift and tell me how to call the instance variable.

Comment: you mean to say something like globale variable which can be furthure used in other controllers ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

its very simple in swift

```
class SharedManager {
   static let sharedInstance = SharedManager()
   var pic = UIImage()
}
```

and to access it

```
SharedManager.sharedInstance.pic = UIImage(named: "imagename")!
```

Here is very good guide about singleton

https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton
https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/

Comment: thnxx a lot.. its so simple but no one posted this  anywhere. thnxx once again.

Comment: @EI Captain v2.0 Is there any difference if I use    static var sharedInstance = SharedManager() instead of    static let sharedInstance = SharedManager()?